# Splitting by lines with Conduit on Windows

Tags: haskell, conduit

I am having some trouble using the conduit lib on to split Text by line.

The source data I'm working with, unfortunately, is extremely inconsistent with line endings, containing both `\r\n` and `\n` sequences in the same file.

I have found the `lines` function in `Data.Conduit.Binary`, but it "splits" by single byte, (`\n`, sensibly enough), which leaves me with a trailing `\r`in some cases.

I understand why the current implementation works the way it does, and I am mostly confident I could hack some kind of a solution together, but the only way I could think of to do this would be something like:

```
lines' = do
   loop $ T.pack ""
   where loop acc = do
         char <- await
         case char of
            Nothing -> return ()
            Just x -> do
            case (isOver $ acc `T.append` x) of
                    (True,y) -> yield y
                    (False,y) -> loop y
                    where isOver n
                           |  (T.takeEnd 2 n == _rLn)  = (True, T.dropEnd 2 n)
                           |  (T.takeEnd 1 n == _Ln)   = (True, T.dropEnd 1 n)
                           |  otherwise                =  (False,n)
                           where _rLn = T.pack $! "\r\n"
                                 _Ln = T.pack $! "\n"
```

... which seems inelegant, kludgy, and terribly slow.

It feels wrong to check the last two characters at every iteration, since all I really need to do is "remember" if the last character I read was `\r`, but I can't think of a sensible way to do that.

Is anyone aware of a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel! We can still make something prettier using [`conduit-combinators`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.16/conduit-combinators-1.0.8.3/Conduit.html). As a foreword, if your `\r` values never occur except sometimes before newlines, you can just filter them out straight up. That said, I am going to assume your case is more general - you only want to get rid of `\r` values that are followed by `\n`.

The idea is to use [`slidingWindowC`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.16/conduit-combinators-1.0.8.3/Conduit.html#v:slidingWindowC) to get two character chunks, then to map these chunks to their first character - unless the characters are `"\r\n"`, in which case we drop both. Then, having removed all `\r` that followed by newlines, we can use the conduit `linesUnboundedC`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Text (Text, singleton, empty)
import Data.MonoTraversable (Element, MonoFoldable)
import Conduit

main = runConduitRes $ (sourceFile "file.txt" :: Producer (ResourceT IO) Text)
                    .| linesUnboundedC'
                    .| printC

-- | Converted a chunked input of characters into lines delimited by \n or \r\n
linesUnboundedC'
  :: (Element a ~ Char, MonoFoldable a, Monad m) => ConduitM a Text m ()
linesUnboundedC' = concatMapC id
                .| slidingWindowC 2
                .| mapC (\cs@[c,_] -> if cs == "\r\n" then empty else singleton c)
                .| linesUnboundedC
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer, thanks so much for the tip about `slidingWindow` - That solves several other problems that I didn't know I had yet.

However, apparently the `Data.Conduit.Text` package has a `foldLines`function that I've just discovered that handles this use-case quite well, so, re: "don't reinvent the wheel" I think I'm going to go with that as the 'correct' answer.

Comment: @IronGremlin Nice find! Go with that for sure - it should be a fair bit faster.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently `Data.Conduit.Text` has a function, `foldLines`, which works precisely as described.